# SQL - Joiners and Leavers - Rows to Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, pivot

I have some data like this which is the leavers and joiners. This is the result of a Group-By, which is why I have duplicate names.

```
Name              | Date                    | Status
----------------------------------------------------
John              | 2016-01-01 09:00:00.000 | Joined
John              | 2017-06-01 17:00:00.000 | Left
Fred              | 2016-01-05 09:00:00.000 | Joined
Fred              | 2016-10-15 17:00:00.000 | Left
```

and I want to transpose it into this: -

```
Name              | Joined                  | Left
---------------------------------------------------------------------
John              | 2016-01-01 09:00:00.000 | 2017-06-01 17:00:00.000
Fred              | 2016-01-05 09:00:00.000 | 2016-10-15 17:00:00.000
```

I've looked at pivot, but I get the impression this will put every single date as a new column. I don't want to concat the dates into one column either.

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: This has been answered like gazillion times in SO :D Please use the search option or Google

Comment: You want a PIVOT, it won't put every date as a new column because you're not going to pivot on that.. you pivot on status of "joined" and "left"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two quick options

**Conditional Aggregation**

```
Select [Name] 
      ,[Joined] = max(case when [Status]='Joined' then [Date] end)
      ,[Left]   = max(case when [Status]='Left'   then [Date] end)
 From  YourTable
 Group By [Name]
```

**Or PIVOT**

```
Select *
 From  YourTable
 Pivot (max([Date]) For [Status] in ([Joined],[Left]) ) p
```

Comment: Thanks John. I went for the top one in the end. With pivot I just get two columns of NULLs for some reason. I need to experiment a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

If you're PIVOT averse you don't have to use that particular keyword:

```
SELECT
  Name,
  MAX(CASE WHEN Status = 'Joined' THEN [Date] END) as [Joined],
  MAX(CASE WHEN Status = 'Left' THEN [Date] END) as [Left]
FROM
  JoinersAndLeavers 
GROUP BY 
  Name
```

Consider what you want to do if there are more than one date pair for a name.. You might choose to use MIN for the joined date for example, to give the earliest join date and the latest leave date..

Answer (score 0):

Result by dynamic sql we will get same result

```
DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
        ,@ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @ColumnName=STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', '+ QUOTENAME([Status]) FROM  #Temp FOR  XML PATH ('')),1,1,'')

SET @DynamicPivotQuery='
                            SELECT Name,'+@ColumnName+'FROM
                            (
                            SELECT * FROM #Temp
                            )
                            AS SRC
                            PIVOT
                            (
                            MAX([Date]) FOR [Status] IN ('+@ColumnName+')
                            )AS PVT
                            '
PRINT @DynamicPivotQuery
EXEC SP_ExecuteSQl @DynamicPivotQuery
```

Result

```
Name              | Joined                  | Left
---------------------------------------------------------------------
John              | 2016-01-01 09:00:00.000 | 2017-06-01 17:00:00.000
Fred              | 2016-01-05 09:00:00.000 | 2016-10-15 17:00:00.000
```